# Request and Response fields are not avilable in my kibana - ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

im new to ELK, we configured the ELK for our application successfully, but we cant analyze with Request, response and url fields in kibana

But I can see those fields in `kibana_sample_data_log` data view.

I doubted, maybe the data which i sent to the elastic from logstash or logstash data preparation have issue.

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: In Kibana go to discovery and look how the format of the events look like, you can use discovery also for searching

Comment: Yes my setup also showing log reports but I can't check request response and which API hits for the perticular log?